# Oracle Row Level Security Static

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, row-level-security

I have a question regarding Row-level Security with Static Policy Type

Example :

- Table => Temp
- RLS Function => Fun_temp

The RLS function is querying the same table Temp to find the predicate based on the current context user, there is no other logic on the sysdate.

Now my Question is :

- If the policy type is STATIC, and I am using this table in the loop and changed the data while the loop is executing, does the predicate changes??
- Does the function execute every time in the loop?

I find it difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

If the policy type is STATIC the predicate will not change. It will be cached in SGA. However if the context parameter value, in your case, user, changes, the predicate will evaluate to a new value for the parameter user in the context. So the output will depend on the new value for the parameter user in the context.

The function will not execute every time. The predicate will be cached in SGA.

[OracleDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm#DBSEG884) for your reference.

Updated:
The above Oracle Documentation clearly states the below.

*The function to generate the dynamic WHERE Clause must not select from a table within the associated policy function. Although you can define a policy against a table, you cannot select that table from within the policy that was defined against the table.*

Comment: what will happen if the table inside the table is changed?

Comment: What do you mean by "table inside the table is changed"? Can you please give a detailed example?

Comment: Added more information from documentation in the answer.